# Identify if an email address is 'public'

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I would like to identify if an email address comes from a public provider or is from an established business. I consider public email addresses to be things such as:

- Open email service providers, such as
  gmail, hotmail and yahoo.
- Anonymization services, such as mailinator or dispostable.

I'm aware that there is no foolproof way to do this, and obviously any list based solution would require constant updates.

Is there a public listing or .NET library that can do this for me?

Comment: It's a great question. We have not found an answer to this need but have been developing our own "white list" of email providers over the years.

Comment: sounds really useful to spammers.

Comment: This isn't for spamming, at least in my intended use case. I want to assign higher limits in our app to potential paying customers, which in our case is those with a business email at sign-up.

Comment: Wow, the assumption that only those using a "business" address will potentially become paying customers seems harsh and arbitrary. Especially when I regularly see people using a "public" address in their business.

Comment: If you want to filter out non-business accounts, ask for their tax id (e.g. EIN), not their email address.

Comment: Let me clarify... There are some features of our app that cost real money to enable for a user (ie. we need to pay others for part of the service). So the idea is to release more of these features to biz addresses rather than hotmail/gmail/yahoo type accounts. In other words, it's just a business decision as to how best to spread the money, not some overly convoluted assumption about who exactly will become a paying customer.

Comment: I agree with @Kirk...I use my public email address sometimes just to make sure any response does not get caught up in the office spam filter.

Comment: Google Apps allows you to use GMail with your own domain name. In this case, you can't even check whether GMail is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there really that many free webmail providers out there?  I would go with a 'blacklisting' style solution.

For example, flag everything in [this wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_webmail_providers) as free (heck I would think covering gmail/hotmail/yahoo/aol would cover a huge % of users anyway).  Then if you get more than 2 (or higher number if your site has high throughput) registrations from the same email domain, it notifies the admin to check the domain to see if it needs to be added to the 'blacklist'.

I would imagine there are much more reliable ways to detect business customers though.  For example in Australia you could just ask for an ABN and then check that it's valid.  Are you willing to punish small business who don't have email providing and just use a generic @gmail account?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to SpamAssasin's freemail list: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/rules/20_freemail_domains.cf.
I suppose, checking against this list is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to talk to the Better-Business-Bureau ( http://www.bbb.org ) and see if they provide some kind of a feed or API.  I had a quick look at their site and couldn't see anything obvious, but it would be this kind of organisation I would head to first if I wanted to find out domain names belonging to established businesses.  They do have a form on their site to search by email address ( http://www.bbb.org/us/Find-Business-Reviews/ )

Comment: I think any such solution would have a large number of false negatives (that is, it wouldn't recognize legitimate business domains). There are lots of reasons that any given domain would not appear at all in any database the BBB has.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [HubSpot blocked domains list](https://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms/what-domains-are-blocked-when-using-the-forms-email-domains-to-block-feature). It is not a guarantee that it is 100% accurate or complete.

They also provide a CSV file that you can download and parse programmatically. Link to CSV file is in the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the ultimate goal is to clean your database from unwanted contacts that will increase the monthly bill. What you can do is the following:

- Create a webhook that is triggered whenever a new contact is added.
- In that webhook (which can be written in any language), check if the contact is in a blacklist (which is gmail/etc...).
- [Remove the contact](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/delete_contact) if it is in a blacklist using an API call (you will need to first get the contact ID, which can be easily retrieved using API).